# Spark: Creating DataFrame gives exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, k-means

I am trying to create DataFrame using spark sqlContext. I have used spark 1.6.3 and scala 2.10.5. Below is my code for creating DataFrames.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import com.knoldus.pipeline.KMeansPipeLine

object SimpleApp{

    def main(args:Array[String]){

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val kMeans = new KMeansPipeLine()
     val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
        ("a@email.com", 12000,"M"),
        ("b@email.com", 43000,"M"),
        ("c@email.com", 5000,"F"),
        ("d@email.com", 60000,"M")
      )).toDF("email", "income","gender")

    val categoricalFeatures = List("gender","email")
    val numberOfClusters = 2
    val iterations = 10
    val predictionResult = kMeans.predict(sqlContext,df,categoricalFeatures,numberOfClusters,iterations)
   }
}
```

Its giving me the following exception. What mistake I am doing? Can anyone help me resolve this?

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
    org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(Lscala/collection/Seq;Lscala/ref lect/api/TypeTags$TypeTag;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;
    at SimpleApp$.main(SimpleApp.scala:24)
    at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

The dependencies I have used are:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.5" 
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( 
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.0.0" % "provided", 
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "2.0.0" % "provided", 
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.0.0" % "provided", 
 "knoldus" % "k-means-pipeline" % "0.0.1" )
```

Comment: Your code works well for me. I'm guessing your Spark binaries were compiled with Scala 2.11 so they can't run with your code using Spark 2.10,  the reverse problem of the one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728731/scala-code-throw-exception-in-spark

Comment: @TzachZohar how can I resolve this?

Comment: First - your dependencies show you're using Spark 2.0.0 not 1.6.3 as you state above. Spark 2.0.0 uses Scala 2.11 by default, as far as I know if you want to use it with Scala 2.10 you'll have to build it yourself, see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-for-scala-210. So - either use Scala 2.11 or use a Spark version compiled according to these instructions.

Answer (score 1):

As I see in your createDataFrame missed second argument. Method pattern described here: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@createDataFrame(org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD,%20java.lang.Class)

In your case it will be

```
def createDataFrame[A <: Product](data: Seq[A])(implicit arg0: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.TypeTag[A]): DataFrame
```

> :: Experimental :: Creates a DataFrame from a local Seq of Product.

OR
Converting Seq into List/RDD and using method pattern with 2 arguments

Comment: not true at all - the second argument is implicit, so one shouldn't have to supply it explicitly. The code in question actually _works_ given the correct dependencies.

Comment: Here are my dependencies:

Comment: scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies  ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
"knoldus" % "k-means-pipeline" % "0.0.1"
)

Comment: Please add these to question, not as a comment;